# Diferenciar contenido traducido de contenido original

Tags: característica-nueva, traducciones-de-contenido

Debido a que hay tanta polémica acerca de la traducción de contenido del sitio SO en inglés para enriquecer el banco de preguntas de SO en español, sugiero que se utilice algún sistema que permita identificar el contenido traducido y también identificar la fuente original del mismo (por medio de etiquetas especiales, campos de información adicionales, etc). Esto podría servir también para llevar estadísticas del desempeño del sitio en su fase beta.

Answer (score 6):

De hecho, ya que el contenido que se aporta a Stack Exchange debe ser licenciado como cc-by-sa, es obligatorio incluir una atribución razonable. Una atribución razonable debe incluir al menos el título original, un enlace a la fuente original, y el nombre de los autores originales.

Lo que Stack Exchange pide para sitios externos es:

- Que se indique que el contenido proviene de Stack Exchange Network.
- Que se enlace a la pregunta original.
- Que se indique los nombres de los autores.
- Que se enlace al perfil de cada autor, y al dominio de Stack Exchange del que provenga el contenido.

En mi opinión, esta información debería estar claramente visible, preferiblemente al comienzo del post, ya que una pequeña nota al final puede pasar desapercibida. Recomendaría algo como:

---

Esta respuesta es una traducción de la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10251097/371250) de [Mysticial (Alexander Yee)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/922184/mysticial) a la pregunta [Why does GCC generate such radically different assembly for nearly the same C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250419/why-does-gcc-generate-such-radically-different-assembly-for-nearly-the-same-c-co) en [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

*Texto traducido*

*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet*

---